# liferay portlet soap client, proxy authentication

Tags: java, soap, liferay, liferay-6

i have a portlet deployed in my Liferay portal (Windows) which somewhere makes a call to a SOAP service like:

```
URL url = new URL("https://walter.dia.fi.upm.es:8443/integrate_collaborative_tools/services/SemanticInteroperabilityLayer?wsdl");
String namespace = "http://QueryEngine";
String serviceName = "SemanticInteroperabilityLayer";
QName serviceQN = new QName(namespace, serviceName);

Service service = Service.create(url,serviceQN);


QName QN = new QName(namespace,"SemanticInteroperabilityLayerHttpsSoap11Endpoint");
SemanticInteroperabilityLayerPortType portType=service.getPort(QN,SemanticInteroperabilityLayerPortType.class);
```

Now, we need to deploy a test server behind a proxy.

How am i going to alter my liferay, OS or code configuration in order to authenticate to proxY?